# (Python NegaMax Algorithm for Game of Nim) What is wrong with my code?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, negamax

I am a new learner of AI. My assignment requires me to write a program in Python that plays the Game of Nim optimally (using the `NegaMax` algorithm).

If you're not familiar with the game, here is a brief description:

Nim is a simple two-player game. We start with a pile of n matches,
where `n ≥ 3`.

Two players, Max and Min, take turns to remove k matches from the pile, where `k = 1, k = 2, or k = 3`. The player who takes the last match loses.

This is what I have already written:

```py
def NegaMax(state, turn, bestmove): 
    max = -100000000000  
    if state == 1:
        if turn == 0:
            return (-1,bestmove)
        else:
            return (1,bestmove)       
    for move in range(1, 4):
        if state-move > 0:
            m = NegaMax(state-move, 1-turn, bestmove)
            m1 = -m[0]
            if m1 > max:
                max = m1
                bestmove = move
    return (max,bestmove)

def play_nim(state):
    turn = 0
    bestmove = 0
    while state != 1:
        [evaluation,move] = NegaMax(state, turn, bestmove)
        print(str(state) + ": " + ("MAX" if not turn else "MIN") + " takes " + str(move))
        state -= move
        turn = 1 - turn
    print("1: " + ("MAX" if not turn else "MIN") + " loses")
```

No matter what number of `state` I put in, both Min and Max always takes 1 match in every round.

I think the problem is that the evaluation is wrong, but I cannot see where I did wrong. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check your stop condition.**

You need :

```
if state == 1:
    return (-1,1)
```

And then everything runs smoothly.

I would also change the function signature for clarity because it only needs `state` :

```
def NegaMax(state):
    max = -100000000000
    if state == 1:
        return (-1,1)
    for move in range(1, 4):
        if state-move > 0:
            m = NegaMax(state-move)
            m1 = -m[0]
            if m1 > max:
                max = m1
                bestmove = move
    return (max,bestmove)

def play_nim(state):
    turn = 0
    while state != 1:
        [evaluation,move] = NegaMax(state)
        print(str(state) + ": " + ("MAX" if not turn else "MIN") + " takes " + str(move))
        state -= move
        turn = 1 - turn
    print("1: " + ("MAX" if not turn else "MIN") + " loses")
```

It plays optimally.

You can observe the results under optimal play, which is that MAX loses for states 1+4k (1, 5, 9, 13, 17, etc) and wins for every other states.

```
play_nim(5)
5: MAX takes 1
4: MIN takes 3
1: MAX loses

play_nim(11)
11: MAX takes 2
9: MIN takes 1
8: MAX takes 3
5: MIN takes 1
4: MAX takes 3
1: MIN loses
```